# How to implement a WrapBootstrap theme with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm trying to understand where to put the CSS, JS, and HTML files from a WrapBootstrap admin theme in my Laravel 5 skeleton app. Anyone with prior experience in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5 then you should put **CSS**, **JS**, **images**, **fonts** etc. in public folder. And You should create Laravel blade template with your **HTML** files. You can find all documentation **[here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade)**. You can call your assets like below way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" type="text/css">
```

Comment: @Conchol Mahmud Are we not supposed to place them instead in the resources>assets folder instead?

Comment: Which file you want to place `resources>assets` ? You should put blade template in resources>view.You can get idea from this structure http://s31.postimg.org/woycywn3v/Capture.png

Comment: I thought we were supposed to place them in the assets folder, as we would have previously done in CodeIgniter, but you are right - public folder is where they go into.